# Call API Gateway from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a use case where a Lambda is event triggered when a new object is created to S3 bucket.

Now in the Lambda, I want to call API Gateway.

s3 object add -> Lambda -> API Gateway

Any code references for calling a API Gateway in Lambda will be helpful.

Comment: It's an HTTP endpoint. You use your usual HTTP API-calling library, like Axios, Requests.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a very broad question but here is a python example of how to call a HTTP endpoint using the requests library which uses basic authentication.. But you shouldn't need to call your API gateway if it is in the same account you could call your lambda directly or send a message to a sqs queue that triggers the lamdba etc.

```
def call_api_gateway():
    json_payload = {
        "key1": "value1"
    }
    url = <your api gateway url>
    id = <depending on your type of authentication specify ID or oauth token etc.>
    secret = <depending on your type of authentication specify password or oauth token etc.>
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application-json"}
    response = requests.post(
            url,
            data=json.dumps(json_payload),
            headers=headers,
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(id, secret),
        )
```